# Прервать Socket.Accept()

Tags: c#, .net

Как прервать `Socket.Accept()`?

Comment: `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, лучше работать с `TcpListener`.

Попробуйте такой код:

```
TcpListener tcpListener;
bool isDying = false;
```

```
// запуск
tcpListener = new TcpListener(connection);
tcpListener.Start();
try
{
    TcpClient client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    // ...
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) // кажется, это будет брошено, если
{                                  // остановить tcpListener
    // проверить, что мы действительно обрываем соединение
    if (!isDying)
        throw;
}
```

```
// обрыв
isDying = true;
tcpListener.Stop();
```

---

Если очень хочется работать именно с сокетом, используйте `tcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync()`. Но `TcpClient` по идее удобнее.

Comment: а сокет получается не прервать никак?

Comment: `Close()`, он же `Dispose()`, обычно прерывает все.

Comment: @max619: Вы можете прервать его, но у него нет async-интерфейса, поэтому вам придётся делать это из другого потока.

Comment: @VladD у сокета же есть метод BeginAccept, а у задачи - Factory.FromAsync... Выглядит, конечно, страшно, но чем не асинхронный интерфейс?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, а хорошая идея. Но с сокетами у меня нет потока с async/await-интерфейсом, я должен работать вручную с Send/Receive. А с TcpClient я могу использовать привычные функции работы с потоком.